# Evaluate a Function to Full Machine Precision

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

If we want to evaluate $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$ then we have to observe its large relative error as $x\to 0$. 
My question is that how can we find a method so that we can compute $f(x)$ to full machine precision for all $|x|<1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant

Comment: the relative error of the ratio will be the sum of the relative errors of numerator and denominator, so you'll just have to make sure these are small.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman How does Padé Approximate help us here? I am failing to see how this would help.

Comment: This is a standard exercise in using Taylor's theorem with remainder.  I've voted to close.

Comment: @user85729 Step 1, use a method to compute a Padé (or min-max) approximant with sufficiently low error on all of [-1,1]. Take as much time as needed, this is a precomputation step. Step 2, store its coefficients, and write a function that applies this rational function to $x$.

Comment: @AndyPutman How would we use the remainder of a Taylor approximation here?